# How to centre map to default location in Google Map API 3 with an a button on the map (not below or above the map)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**First of all this is not a duplicate question . Other questions on Stack overflow and other sites don't have the complete thing I am asking for. I do not want a button below the iframe.**

**I want a button say button like a small red circle over the map in the down right corner of the iframe**

[Red Circle Button Sample - I want to keep a button like this in bottom right corner of the div/iframe](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/9/P/m/2/g/transparent-red-circle-md.png)

I have created a fiddle to make you understand the issue.The link is at the last part of the question

Code

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
var map;
var marker;
var location1 = {
lat: 34.0522,
lng: -118.2437
};

  function initMap() {
  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: location1,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location1,
  map: map,
  title: 'Click to zoom'
});
  } 

 function changeCenter(center) {
  map.setCenter(center);
  marker.setPosition(center);
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);">Location 1</button>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px
}
#map {
height: 90%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Also another thing that is not happening - I have kept the default zoom level at 13 , now when I am zooming in 3 times or say zooming out 3 times then when I click on the button I am getting zoom location of my default position as 10 or 16, not that original 13. Please help me with this thing also

**@saravana has only solved a little part of my question.**

Here is my updated fiddle

[updated FIDDLE with zoom issue solved](https://jsfiddle.net/8s8jcLty/2/)

**The major thing is still there - I want to create a custom button over the map. Please help me with that**

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your changecenter function to below code

```
function changeCenter(center) {
    map.setCenter(center);
    map.setZoom(13); 
    marker.setPosition(center);
}
```

You can set zoom level by using map.setZoom() function. Cheers!!!

**Update:**

Please replace your html code to below code in fiddle

we have to add custom button or image manually in the google map. I hope this will help

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/X/9/P/m/2/g/transparent-red-circle-md.png" width="25px" style="position: fixed;z-index: 9999; right:10px; top:225px; float: right;" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  var marker;
  var location1 = {
    lat: 34.0522,
    lng: -118.2437
  };

  function initMap() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: location1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location1,
      map: map,
      title: 'Click to zoom'
    });
      } 

  function changeCenter(center) {
      map.setCenter(center);
      map.setZoom(13);
      marker.setPosition(center);
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);">Location 1</button>
```

Comment: brother you only solved a little part of my question. The major thing is still there - I want to create a custom button over the map. Please help me with that